# Como puedo pasar un id como un valor a un metodo en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de pasar el valor de un id a un metodo como se muestra en la imagen pero no entiendo como pasarlo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que lo más importante es.... Por qué tienes la necesidad de hacerlo? En el patrón *Modelo-Vista-Controlador (MVC)*, el Modelo **debería**, idealmente, llevar TODOS los datos que la vista debe presentar; el modelo le dice a la vista qué mostrar, no al contrario. Tu *Modelo* y sus datos **NO DEBEN** depender de lo que haya en la *Vista*. La *Vista*, idealmente, **NO TIENE LÓGICA DE NEGOCIOS**. Así que... Nuevamente, qué quieres hacer? Por qué sientes la necesidad de pasar ese Id? Parece más un problema X-Y. Intentas solucionar un problema a una solución errónea del problema original

Comment: En tu imagen el id es el id que le pondrá al select del html que se genera. Tu le llamaste "drpItem" y quieres ponerlo en la funcion Model.UnidadMedida. No entiendo porque no puedes escribirlo y punto. Pero me parece que tu problema es otro